# Yajra DataTable search bar is not working

Tags: laravel-5.4, yajra-datatable

I have used Left Join Query in file called "directoryDataTable.php. Now the problem is that Yajra DataTable search bar is not working. Its neither giving any error nor the search result.

My DataTable query function is al follows.

```
 public function query()
{
    $id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id;
    $directories = DB::table('directories')
        ->leftjoin('claimed', 'directories.id', '=','claimed.dir_id')
        ->select('directories.*')
        ->where('directories.user_id',$id)
        ->where('paymentStatus','1')
        ->whereNull('directories.deleted_at')
        ->orWhere('claimed.claimed_by',$id);


   return $this->applyScopes($directories);
}
```

Please Help

Comment: Post the part where you actually give the query to Yajra,and also can you store the resultset of the query and log that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the query to,

```
public function query()
{
    $id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id;
    $directories = DB::table('directories')
        ->leftjoin('claimed', 'directories.id', '=','claimed.dir_id')
        ->select('directories.*')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('directories.user_id',\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id)
                ->orWhere('claimed.claimed_by',\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id);
        })
        ->where('paymentStatus','1')
        ->whereNull('directories.deleted_at')
        ;

    return $this->applyScopes($directories);

}
```

and in get columns function, replace ['name' => 'YourTableName.ColumnName','data' => 'YourColumnName'] Like this.

```
private function getColumns()
{
    return [
        'dir_name' => ['name' => 'directories.dir_name', 'data' => 'dir_name'],

        'phone_number' => ['name' => 'directories.phone_number', 'data' => 'phone_number'],

        'address' => ['name' => 'directories.address', 'data' => 'address'],

        'features' => ['name' => 'directories.features', 'data' => 'features', ],

        'Status' => ['name' => 'directories.Status', 'data' => 'Status','searchable'=>false ],

        'Subscription' => ['name' => 'directories.Subscription', 'data' => 'Subscription','searchable'=>false ]
    ];
}
```